# Automatically highlight Excel cell changes

Tags: microsoft-excel

At my work, we often edit many times the same excel documents and create many versions. In order to let the reviewer know what changes are made after each modification, we need to highlight all the changes made, there are VBA codes to automatically highlight the changed cell in excel spreadsheet from an internet search, however, none of them addresses the need that sometimes within each edit, you will edit twice the same cell so that the original value is reinstated,i.e. if

I modify cell `A1` from 'yes' to 'no', then after second thought, I change it to yes again, `A1` is still highlighted(meaning this cell is changed), but in fact, it's not. Is there a way to work this out?

Comment: Why not use cell comments? Each person who edits the cell can amend the comment, and the reviewer can clear them out when they're done.

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the wheel, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-22aea671-cac7-4fa3-845d-eeb23725bd15

Comment: @spikey_richie that's the reviewers requirement to highlight each cell i have made change to, so that when he reviews he only needs to look at those highlighted cells...and the cell comment function you mentioned is also manual right?Is it like to insert comment and edit in the comment box?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is referred to as a **Document Control SOP**.  Excel is not going to offer you a solution whether directly or indirectly, but it can still be used given that proper training is implemented and practices are monitored and enforced.  This may vary widely depending upon your industry, but here's an example guidance for the Food Safety industry:

SQF Mod 2 Guidance (See pages [19 ~ 22](https://www.sqfi.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/Mod-2-packaging-Guidance-wth-cover.pdf#page=19))

ISO also offers their own standards, as do many other benchmarks and auditing schemes.  From there, you build your own SOP as well as document form templates to assist in your document control practices.  Here's an example for tracking via Excel files:

[image: Table of Contents]
[image: Revisions Register]

And here's an example of what form headers / footers you may want to include to assist in document control:

[image: Form Example]

Comment: Tks a lot, somehow this is quite a good control of document changes and tracking, what i am looking for is not as complicated. We don't need to formally document the changes, only how to highlight it so that the reviewer would know what are changed, and i wish those be done automatically instead of manually.